# JNDI modify an attribute in multiple entries simultaneously

Tags: java, jndi

I know that its possible to search for an attribute inside all entries in LDAP. After searching, I want to remove that attribute from all the entries which contains it.
One way to do this is to iterate through all the entries and invoke `DirContext.modifyAttributes(name, mods)` on each entry. I want to know is there any simple way to do this, like I can remove it from all entries in one shot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a DN-valued attribute and your LDAP server supports referential integrity you can delete it from all attributes by deleting the entry with that DN, but that's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: yes, I have an attribute with the same value in multiple DNs and I want to delete it from all DNs...